# Fassbinder and Almodóvar’s subversion of the heterosexual male gaze: scholarship and parallels?

Tags: casting, directors

A number of auteurs have had favorite actresses that they discovered and cast from one film to another (e.g. Godard, Rivette, Truffaut). Rainer Werner Fassbinder and Pedro Almódovar are certainly among directors fond of writing prominent female roles and using and reusing certain actresses for them. However, at least I have been struck by how unusual some of the women they cast are. In spite of Fassbinder and Almódovar sometimes depicting these women in the same glamorous circumstances and attire as one might find from other filmmakers, the women themselves have physical features that do not conform to prevalent expectations of beauty and, one suspects, would disqualify them from other filmmakers’ casting. My own personal assumption would be that this is due to Fassbinder and Almódovar both being gay filmmakers, which gave them a different vantage point than the typical heterosexual male gaze of the majority of their fellow filmmakers (yet not, interestingly, the complete disinterest in the female form of, say, Tom of Finland). Is there any existing scholarship on this phenomenon, and are there other filmmakers that are deemed to have made similarly unconventional casting choices?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Movies & TV.  This question seems a bit broad to fit with how the site works; you're asking both for a survey of scholarship and a list of other creators.  Even either of those taken in turn might be difficult to answer properly, given the limitations of the question-answer format for addressing requests for lists of things.  You would be better served by narrowly focusing on a single question; you might want to take the [tour] for an overview of how to get the most out of the site.

Comment: Have you searched Google Scholar, or a library?

Answer (score 5):

I cannot speak about Fassbinder, but remember that Almodovar is Spanish and make movies mostly for a Spanish audience. The beauty standard of actors with fit bodies, perfect hair and teeth, and perfect skin with no wrinkles, is mostly a US standard. This standard is spread all around the world (see South Korea, where it is nigh impossible for a woman to make a career in acting if she is not absolutely beautiful) but you can watch movies and shows from other countries to see other beauty standards.

For example, you can have a look at Money Heist (a Spanish show) or Dark (a German show) and see that they don't conform to the same standards of physical appearance.

Also, Almodovar is representative of the [the Movida](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/La_Movida_Madrile%C3%B1a), this Spanish countercultural movement born after the death of Franco, and who expressed a strong opposition to conservatism and a desire for sexual freedom.

Comment: 'Almodovar is Spanish and make movies mostly for a Spanish audience' - I dispute that.